# Rewrite nested search in JSValue

Tags: scala, play-json

I wrote the following function - which a little bit of JAVA way for me, I wanted to convert it to a more Scala way

```scala
@tailrec
private[services] final def nestedSearch(payload: JsValue, name: String): JsLookupResult = {
  val arrRegex = "([\\w]+)\\[([\\d]+)\\]".r

  def currLevelSearch(payload: JsValue, name: String): JsLookupResult = {
    name match {
      case arrRegex(arr, index) if Try(index.toInt).isSuccess => payload \ arr \ index.toInt // name is from the form arr[index], NOTE: by regex index is decimal => index.toInt is safe but still double-check
      case _ => payload \ name
    }
  }

  name indexOf "." match {
    case lastSearch if lastSearch < 0 => currLevelSearch(payload, name)
    case currSearch if currSearch >= 0 =>
      val `until first .` = name.substring(0, currSearch)
      val `after first .` = name.substring(currSearch + 1)
      currLevelSearch(payload, `until first .`) match {
        case JsDefined(newPayload) => nestedSearch(newPayload, `after first .`)
        case undefined: JsUndefined => undefined
      }
  }
}
```

The function gets as a input JsValue and name, for instance `name: a.b.c.d[0].e` and its find the JsValue field that matchs this key in nested, for example:

```json
{
    "a": {
        "b": {
            "c": {
                "d": [
                    {
                        "firstElement": {
                            "e": "foundValue!"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Other idea was with `.split` which i also probably think there some better way to handle this issue, the implementation is bellow:

```
  private[services] final def nestedSearch(payload: JsValue, name: String): JsLookupResult = {
    val arrRegex = "([\\w]+)\\[([\\d]+)\\]".r

    @tailrec def nestedSearchRec(keys: List[String])(seed: JsLookupResult): JsLookupResult = keys match {

      // Base cases:
      case Nil => seed
      case _ if seed.isEmpty => seed

      // Step case:
      case name :: tail =>
        nestedSearchRec(tail) {
          name match {
            case arrRegex(arr, index) => seed \ arr \ index.toInt
            case name => seed \ name
          }
        }
    }

    nestedSearchRec(name.split('.').toList)(JsDefined(payload))
  }
```

Any ideas on how to re-write this code in functional proper scala way?
Thanks!

**NOTE:** Im using scala `2.12.8` and `play-json` library

---

**Thanks to @Tomer Shetah** The function upgraded to:

```
private[services] final def nestedSearch(payload: JsValue, name: String): JsLookupResult = {
    val arrRegex = "([\\w]+)\\[([\\d]+)\\]".r
    JsPath {
      name.split("\\.").toList.flatMap {
        case arrRegex(node, index) => List(KeyPathNode(node), IdxPathNode(index.toInt))
        case s => List(KeyPathNode(s))
      }
    }(payload) match {
      case Nil => JsUndefined(s"Could not find $name in $payload")
      case res :: _ => JsDefined(res)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
val jsPath = JsPath \ "a" \ "b" \ "c" \ "d" \\ "firstElement" \ "e"
val json = Json.parse(jsonString)

println(jsPath(json))
```

This will result with:

```
List("foundValue!")
```

Please note that `\\` will get all elements in the array. For example if in the array in `d` there will be a sibling:

```json
{
    "firstElement": {
        "e": "foundValue!"
    }
}
```

than the result will be:

```
List("foundValue!", "foundValue!2")
```

You ask for the first element, so to get it you can do:

```
jsPath(json).headOption
```

In case you need to convert the path `"a.b.c.d[0].firstElement.e"` into `JsPath`, you can do:

```
val path: List[PathNode] = pathString.split("\\.").toList.flatMap {
  case s"$node[$index]" if index.toIntOption.isDefined =>
    List(KeyPathNode(node), IdxPathNode(index.toInt))
  case s=>
    List(KeyPathNode(s))
}
```

Then calling:

```
val jsPath = JsPath(path)
val json = Json.parse(jsonString)
println(jsPath(json))
```

Will result with:

```
List("foundValue!")
```

Code run at [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/toshetah/3RHrUJPwRCK8koNQvSjXvQ/4).

Comment: BTW you can also do: `val jsPath = JsPath \ "a" \ "b" \ "c" \ "d" \ 0 \ "firstElement" \ "e"`

Comment: Amazing! thanks for the help @Tomer shetah :) - btw any advantages of using JsPath over the old recursion? (performance and etc)

Comment: I don't think there is a major performance difference between the two options. First, the scale is really small. Second, in your approach you are using regexes many times. Which is not very efficient. So it miGht be that you improve the performance with tail recursion, but I assume that the improvement will be minor.